# Double forward slash in URL behaves differently from local PC and Azure Web App

Tags: asp.net-core, azure-web-app-service

Our ASP.NET Core 3.1 Web app must handle requests like this:

http://myappbaseurl//api/ApiAccount/userinfo (note the double forward slashes)

The problem is that while debugging this code locally (VS2019 latest update) the request is received WITHOUT the double slashes.

But with the deployed version in Azure App Services, the request contains the double slashes.

Where is this difference coming from? How can I have the same behaviour (local pc and Azure App Service)?

Comment: Rewrite the URL at the web server-level, e.g. for IIS, you can use the URL Rewrite Module to automatically redirect `http://myappbaseurl//api/ApiAccount/userinfo` to `http://myappbaseurl/api/ApiAccount/userinfo`.

Comment: Actually my workaround happens on the Startup.Configure method where I use the IApplicationBuilder.Use function for this "redirect". But my question was more in the sense to understand the cause of the difference in behaviour when running the app locally or published in Azure.